# How do you remove a class object from a hashset?

Tags: java, hashset

Im quite new to programming so i apologise if this is a stupid question.. how do I remove an object from a hashset? I've tried to use .remove() but im doing something wrong because it doesn't work for the object

```
public class Pocket
{
    private HashSet<Penny> myset;
    
    public Pocket(int PocketSize)
    {
        myset = new HashSet<Penny>();
        while (PocketSize > myset.size()){
            myset.add(new Penny());
        }
    public int pennyCount()
    {
        return myset.size();
        
    }
    public Penny removePenny(){
        if (myset.size() > 0){
            myset.remove(Penny);
        } else{
            return null;
}
    }
```

I want the method removePenny() to remove one penny object from my set that I initialised previously. if anyone can help that would be great thanks.

Comment: You use `remove()` to remove a *specific* object. Since all your `Penny` objects seem to be equivalent, I'm not sure why you're using a `Set` at all. Could just have a counter.

Comment: You don't need an `if` in your `remove` method, just call the method. But you need to return something, it does not make sense to return a `Penny` there.

Answer (score 1):

That is not how `Set`s work.

Firstly, adding multiple pennies to a set does not work the way you want it to

- if `Penny` has proper `equals` / `hashCode` implementations then there will always only be at most one penny in the `Set` since `Penny` apparently has no arguments and therefore all `Penny` instances would have to be considered equal.
- if `Penny` has no proper `equals` / `hashCode` implementation then it should not be in a `Set` to begin with. You can only remove such a `Penny` if you have the exact same instance that is already in the set because that instance is the only one that would be equal to itself.

Lastly `Set`s do not support deletion based on the type of the instances it contains.

You need to entirely rethink what you are trying to achieve and how you want to model that. Probably not using a `Set`.